# Declaring list with anonymous type

Tags: c#, .net, list, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to declare list which has anonymous type in it. I have tried to assign list value to null and also tried to assign list to new entity list but it shows error. Any pointers?

```
var finalEntries = new List<MyDbTableEntity>();

var groupedItemList = _context.MyDbTableEntity
                      .Select(k => new { name = k.name.ToString(), data = k.info.ToString() })
                      .GroupBy(k => k.name)
                      .ToList();

finalEntries.AddRange(groupedItemList);
```

Error

```
cannot convert from 
'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, <anonymous type: string name, string data>>>' 
to 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyDbTableEntity>'
```

Comment: Sorry just have to ask, isnt the error you are receiving kind of obvious? It is exactly telling you what went wrong that `IEnumerable<MyDbTableEntity>` isnt equal to `List<IGrouping<string, <anonymous type>>>` ? So your only choice is to make them equal, or atleast some common base class if you dont have a common base class than `object` since everything is an `object`.

Comment: I tried and could not figure out how to pass anonymous parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not work because you have a typed list of `MyDbTableEntity`. You cannot add a different type on this typed list. Try to define the right type?

```
var finalEntries = new List<MyDbTableEntity>();

var groupedItemList = _context.MyDbTableEntity
                      .Select(k => new MyDbTableEntity { Name = k.name.ToString(), Data = k.info.ToString() })
                      .GroupBy(k => k.Name)
                      .ToList();

finalEntries.AddRange(groupedItemList);
```

or it or change it to a list of `object`.

```
var finalEntries = new List<object>();

// not sure about your type
var groupedItemList = _context.MyDbTableEntity
                      .Select(k => new { name = k.name.ToString(), data = k.info.ToString() })
                      .GroupBy(k => k.name)
                      .ToList();

finalEntries.AddRange(groupedItemList);
```

**Importante**: The problem of this is when you lose this scope you will not get a typed anonymous type, I mean, you will need to use some artifacts to read the properties, for sample: use `reflection` to convert the type into a `dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `Select().GroupBy().ToList()` essentially returns a list of lists. The top level list contains all the groups created by GroupBy() while the second level **lists** contain the rows for each group returned from the Select() method. These are anonymous typed objects which are totally different from MyDbTableEntity

Neither the list of groups, nor the anonymous typed objects are convertable to your MyDbTableEntity type. To demonstrate what I mean, if you removed the Select() statement (and therefore the anonymous types) you could change the last line to the following and it would work:

```
foreach(var items in groupedItemList) finalEntries.AddRange(items);
```

Of course, this defeats the purpose of grouping in the first place but it does demonstrate one aspect of why the original code didn't work. The second aspect was demonstrated by the removal of the Select() statement

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
    class Person {
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName) {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }
    }

    Person[] people = {
        new Person("Fred", "Bloggs"),
        new Person("Linda", "Bloggs"),
        new Person("Joe", "Bloe"),
        new Person("Jane", "Bloe"),
        new Person("Fred", "Flinstone")};

    public void Test() {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();     

        // This works   
        var peopleGroupedByLastName = people.GroupBy(k => k.LastName).ToList();
        foreach(var grp in peopleGroupedByLastName) {
            // The grp var holds a list of Person objects, each with the same last name
            list.AddRange(grp); // Pointless, but works
        }

        // The following will not even compile because the anonymous typed objects are
        // not compatible with Person objects, despite having exactly the same fields
        var peopleGroupedByLastName2 = people
            .Select(k => new { FirstName = k.FirstName, LastName = k.LastName })
            .GroupBy(k => k.LastName)
            .ToList();
        foreach(var grp in peopleGroupedByLastName2)
            list.AddRange(grp); // Not "Person" objects
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var finalEntries = Enumerable.Empty<MyDbTableEntity>()
                      .Select(k => new MyDbTableEntity { Name = k.name.ToString(), Data = k.info.ToString() })
                      .GroupBy(k => k.Name)
                      .ToList();

var groupedItemList = _context.MyDbTableEntity
                      .Select(k => new MyDbTableEntity { Name = k.name.ToString(), Data = k.info.ToString() })
                      .GroupBy(k => k.Name)
                      .ToList();

finalEntries.AddRange(groupedItemList);
```

http://rextester.com/KNLMR37736